# HTML5 History/State API, AJAX, PHP redirect, URL change

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, html5-history

My site uses History.js HTML5 History/State API (pushState, statechange event etc) and loads the page into my .content div via AJAX (jQuery).

Works fine until I do a URL redirection server side (CakePHP $this->redirect($url);). The content updates fine with the page I redirected to, but I would like to add a new state to the history.

How should I do this? Is there a way I can check the AJAX response to know if the request was redirected or should I approach the problem from another direction?

**Example**

Admin listing of blog posts. /posts/index
User selects a post. /posts/open/13
User clicks "Delete post" /posts/delete/13

After deleting from DB, the request gets redirected to the listing, but the address bar is still /posts/delete/13
I would like to replace the current state (/posts/delete/13) with the new URL to the history (/posts/index). But how would I know if the AJAX request was redirected or not?

Comment: What exactly do you want to add to the history?

Comment: Original question updated with an example. Thank you

Comment: @rhinoeli Do your server side scripts return JSON encoded respones? Like e.g. `{status:200, url:'/posts/index'}`

Comment: @MarkusHofmann No, response is plain html.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a (IMO) temporary solution.

Server side redirection: check if the request is async. If yes, do not redirect, instead add a "redirect-to" header to the response and send it (body is empty). Client side check the response if it has the header. If yes, do a replaceState and make a new ajax call for the received "redirect-to" url.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Did you maybe come up with another solution? Yours seems to be a good way out, but, you must admit it, it's a hack a little bit :)

Comment: Yes it is clearly a hack. I changed it a little bit. Instead of making a new ajax request based on the header, I do the redirection server side and check the result header for the correct URL and change the state if it is not the same. It is still a hack, but I don't have to do a new http request with client side code for a simple redirection.

Comment: Exactly! I did this way. I didn't find any better solution. Update your answer saying the real answer is in the comment section. And then, accept it.